# git-lint pylint not running pylintrc file

Tags: python, git, pylint, pylintrc

I am using [git-lint](https://github.com/sk-/git-lint) for my Python project.

I have a `.gitlint.yaml` file in the root of my git repo, which contains, among other things,

```
pylint:
  extensions:
  - .py
  command: pylint
  arguments:
  - "--rcfile={DEFAULT_CONFIGS}/.pylintrc" # doesn't seem to work
  - "--disable=all" # doesn't work either
  - "--output-format=text"
  - "--msg-template='{{abspath}}:{{line}}:{{column}}: [{{category}}:{{symbol}}] {{obj}}: {{msg}}'"
  - "--reports=n"
  filter: "^{filename}:(?P<line>{lines}):((?P<column>\\d+):)? \\[(?P<severity>.+):(?P<message_id>\\S+)\\]\\s+(: )?(?P<message>.+)$"
  installation: "Run pip install pylint."
```

I have even created a `~/.config/pylintrc` file, which contains, among other things,

```
indent-string=\t
```

But when i run `git lint`, no warnings are disabled, especially not the `line 41, col 0: Warning: [mixed-indentation]: Found indentation with tabs instead of spaces` warning.

I have concluded (and verified) that the `~/.config/pylintrc` file isn't being processed at all.

Why is pylint ignoring all configuration options?  What troubleshooting steps can I take?  My best guess is that pylint, when executed by git lint, is run by some user other than me.

Comment: Perhaps I need to do something to set DEFAULT_CONFIGS to the repo directory?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I see in [`test/unittest/test_gitlint.py`](https://github.com/sk-/git-lint/blob/34d738e0a2a12828b28cd0556d1a20447357c0fa/test/unittest/test_gitlint.py#L481):

```
self.root = '/home/user/repo'
git_config = os.path.join(self.root, '.gitlint.yaml')
```

So your configuration should be in the right place.
But check if you don't have a cache issue ([`/home/user/.git-lint/cache`](https://github.com/sk-/git-lint/blob/34d738e0a2a12828b28cd0556d1a20447357c0fa/test/unittest/test_utils.py#L105)), as mentioned in [issue 34](https://github.com/sk-/git-lint/issues/34).

> If `.gitlint.yaml` has been updated since the cache was written, the output cache should be invalidated.
>   Otherwise, you could edit the config to eg ignore an error type, but it'll still be present when rerunning.

Comment: You're right, there was a cache issue.  And I guess there's no solution for that issue either.  Also, I've confirmed that the `{DEFAULT_CONFIGS}/.pylintrc` path wasn't working either.  When I replace it with an absolute path, it works.  Do you know where I can set the `DEFAULT_CONFIGS` variable?

Comment: @mareoraft not sure: I see it defined here: https://github.com/sk-/git-lint/blob/34d738e0a2a12828b28cd0556d1a20447357c0fa/gitlint/linters.py#L137-L139. And I can see for v0.0.5 (https://github.com/sk-/git-lint/blob/34d738e0a2a12828b28cd0556d1a20447357c0fa/README.rst#v005-2014-05-09) that "variables `%(REPO_HOME)` and `%(DEFAULT_CONFIGS)` can be specified in configuration"

Comment: They fail to explain where and how those variables should be specified.

Answer (score 1):

I ran into the same issue. My workaround was to remove the rcfile argument line in the `.gitlint.yaml` file.

Then, it picked up the right rcfile based on [how pylint searches for it](https://docs.pylint.org/en/1.6.0/run.html). Also, I needed to delete the cache directory with:

```
rm -r ~/.git-lint/cache
```